# How to fix 'Index Out Of Range' Error in a JSON Parsed app

Tags: arrays, swift

I am finding a small issue with my [code](https://github.com/JosephRogers94/ios-itunes-search). The issue I am having is that my limit call works fine and all, but if you run it and switch the amount shown option a few times, the index out of range error will arise.

It only seems to happen if you run it quickly or don't change up your search. I have spent 4 hours on this and feel I am just not seeing something really simple! Thank you!

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath)

        let searchResult = searchResultsController.searchResults[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = searchResult.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = searchResult.creator
        return cell
    }

    //MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func filterButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if limitSearchButton.title == "show 10" {
            limit.limit = "10"
            limitSearchButton.title = "show 5"
            print("limit is \(String(describing: limit.limit))")
            searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar)
            tableView.reloadData()
        } else if limitSearchButton.title == "show 5"{
            limit.limit = "5"
            limitSearchButton.title = "show 10"
            print("limit is \(String(describing: limit.limit))")
            searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

    @IBAction func segmentedControlChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }else {
            searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }


}

extension SearchResultsTableViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        guard let searchTerm = searchBar.text else { return }

        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            resultType = .software
        case 1:
            resultType = .musicTrack
        case 2:
            resultType = .movie
        default:
            break
        }
        searchResultsController.performSearch(searchTerm: searchTerm, resultType: resultType, limit: limit) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect with my print statements and filter function, to get the limit amount and return it along with updating my button. But I get nothing after a few uses of that UIBarButton Function.

Comment: This is probably a race condition between the threads (when you get new results). Try moving the DispatchQueue.main.async { } calls into your searchResultsController class, around each of your completion blocks. That way the caller doesn't need to worry about it.

Comment: It was this Paul! Thank you!

Comment: If you make that solution an answer I’ll mark it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why the Crash?

This is a race condition between the threads (when you get new results asynchronously).

Sometimes you are trying to display 4 elements, but your data source just updated and now there are 3 elements. You lack synchronization on the model changing.

With all your calls to reloadData, there's a higher chance that it'll be the same time as the network request returns, which I suspect is leading to the crash.

### API Fix

One way to enforce your concurrency would be to move all the concurrency synchronization work to the API, so the consumer of the API doesn't have to think about how it works. (no more client side Dispatch async calls)

In your API logic, wrap every `completion()` handler call, and changes to public properties accessed in the ViewController, with your `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` block. That dispatch queue will enforce that no UI updates are happening on a different thread.

Any APIs you call in your ViewController will be on the same main thread, so you'll get thread safety as long as you put these blocks in each appropriate spot.

Since you didn't provide that code, I'll provide a code sample from another iOS project at [Lambda School](https://lambdaschool.com).

Your logic would look something like this in your URLSession/networking code:

```swift
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error fetching quakes: \(error)")
        DispatchQueue.main.async { // Wrap every call to completion()
            completion(nil, error)
        }
        return
    }

    guard let data = data else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(nil, QuakeError.noDataReturned)
        }
        return
    }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .millisecondsSince1970

        let quakeResults = try decoder.decode(QuakeResults.self, from: data)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Setting a public property needs to be also protected
            // inside your main.async blocks, in addition to your 
            // completion() handler calls

            self.quakes = quakeResults.features  // protect public properties
            completion(quakes, nil)
        }
    } catch {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    }

}.resume()
```